# Why omitting articles in "get out of [something]"?

Tags: grammar, articles

Why is it ok to omit an article in a sentence using the `get out of` expression:

> He gets out of jail.

instead of

> He gets out of ***a***/***the*** jail.

[I found this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26218/in-which-situations-is-it-ok-to-omit-articles-in-short-sentences), but it is somehow not really relating to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He gets out of jail.

"Jail" refers more to the (generic) situation of being deprived of liberty.

> He gets out of **the** jail.

In this case, "the jail" refers more to the building where he was incarcerated.

Comment: The general rule given is too imprecise. Constructions like "The lion is an apex predator" (introducing a hypothetical individual to stand in for a generic group) are fairly common in English. Likewise, "Trump is President of the US" (using the zero article) is not more generic than "the President", but instead more specific.

Comment: "The general rule given is too imprecise." That is precisely why I said "**A** general rule". I am not able at this moment to provide a better general rule. Regarding "Trump is President of the US", it may be idiomatic, but I think that the definite article would find a good use there. I am European non-native English speaker.

Comment: My point was that the general rule given is too imprecise to even be mentioned as a rule at all. It's just not worth putting in an answer: the exceptions are too common, and it's counterproductive to learn.

Comment: OK, no general rule :)